# Почему не работает код на С++

Tags: c++

Добрый вечер!

Мне дана задача: вводятся 2 координаты одного отрезка, затем другого, надо вывести YES, если пересекаются, и NO, если нет.  Пример:

> ввод:
>
> 0 0 1 1  2 0 1 1
>
> вывод:
>
> YES

[Вот мой код, неработающий на указанном там тесте](http://ideone.com/Kypu45), подскажите, в чем проблема?

Comment: Tl;dr.

А вы не пробовали пройти под отладчиком?

Answer (score 1):

[[@Hashirama](/users/22520/hashirama)](/users/22520/hashirama), неправильная работа с векторами, начиная от определения и заканчивая выходом за его пределы (остальное уже не стал проверять). Если это ваш код, то вы хотя бы его поэтапно проверяли во время написания. Уже с первых строк программа должны была упасть при запуске.